# Group policy user settings apply on one computer but i dont want to apply on other

Tags: group-policy

I want to apply gpo with user setting on computer but I don't want to apply this gpo on another computer. I try to use Accounting security settings and wmi filters. No luck. Any suggestion ?

Thx

Comment: User settings apply to users, not computers, unless you use Loopback policy processing. Exactly how are you configuring filtering on this GPO? Please give us as much detail as possible and screenshots if possible.

Comment: I use Folder Redirection in GPO and I want that users don't have Folder Redirection on certain computers because some legacy application can work with UNC path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is to put the computer into its own OU and apply the policy to the OU. If that isn't feasible, a WMI filter can do this.

Namespace: root/CIMv2

Query: select name from Win32_ComputerSystem where Name = 'MyComputerName'

Comment: I am not sure is  WMI filter works only for Computer Configuration in GPO ?

Comment: It works for either. As long as the WMI filter returns true, the policy will run.